# Average ratio formula in excel

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-formula

I've got two cells with the following data in them:

```
W7=2:1, W8=2:1
```

I am trying to get the average of these two cells but cannot figure it out since they are ratios. Obviously, the average should come out to 2:1 since (2:1 + 2:1) / 2 = 2:1 but it doesn't seem to be that simple when trying to calculate in Excel.

**Is there a formula that can achieve this?**

A little side note, the formula I am using to create the ratio is:

```
=ROUND((U8-M8)/(M8-V8),2)&":1"
```

So you can see, the 1 is just added and will be the same every time. That number is not actually being calculated.

Comment: To understand the logic,what would be the average of 3:1 and 4:1?

Comment: Have you considered using a simpler `=(U8-M8)/(M8-V8)` formula with a custom number format of `0.0#\:\1`?

Comment: If you can turn the `2:1` into `2` or `3:1` into `3` or `2:3` into `.6667` you could get an average of the decimal value of the ratios then convert back to `n:y` status. First part is easy by replacing `:` with '/`. Converting decimal to `n:y` status is trickier. For example if the average of `3:1` and `4:1` is `3.5:1` then ratio could be `7:2`

Comment: @NiteshHalai the average would be 3.5:1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can be happy with a result of `4:2` then,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--REPLACE(W7:W8, FIND(":", W7:W8), LEN(W7:W8), TEXT(,)))&":"&SUMPRODUCT(--REPLACE(W7:W8, 1, FIND(":", W7:W8), TEXT(,)))
```

If you want to try and resolve the ratio down to x:1, VBA may be a better solution.

Per your recent addendum to the question, perhaps this will work.

```
=ROUND(SUMPRODUCT(--REPLACE(W7:W8, FIND(":", W7:W8), LEN(W7:W8), TEXT(,)))/COUNTA(W7:W8), 2)&":1"
```

Comment: this worked! I don't know what any of it really means but you're a genie. Thank you so much!